# How to display dashboard

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I have written code that is supposed to display  a dashboard. However, when i call the function no result or error message. What have i left out?

```
def make_dashboard(x, gdp_change, unemployment, title, file_name):
output_notebook('output.html')


x=df_x[['date']],
gdp_change=df_gdp_change[['change-current']],
unemployment=df_unemployment[['unemployment']],
title=GDPvsUnemployment,
file_name=index.html


make_dashboard_show(df_x[['date']],df_gdp_change[['change-current']],df_unemployment[['unemployment']],GDPvsUnemployment,index.html)
```

The result should be a graphical dashboard but i'm not getting an error message or  output

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
make_dashboard(x=x, gdp_change=gdp_change, unemployment= unemployment, title=title, file_name=file_name)
```